# Why is JS "filtering with search field and button filters" not working for me?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement JavaScript in my website, to search and filter elements, from this CodePen: https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/mCdbD

This is the webpage: https://www.exploreloudoncounty.com/explore/

I have copied the code exactly and it is not working. I thought it may have been conflicting with other JavaScript in the page, but I tried removing the others, as well as including the JS in an external file and loading it within the HTML with no luck.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

JS:

```
// quick search regex
var qsRegex;
var buttonFilter;

// init Isotope
var $grid = $(".grid").isotope({
  itemSelector: ".element-item",
  layoutMode: "fitRows",
  filter: function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var searchResult = qsRegex ? $this.text().match(qsRegex) : true;
    var buttonResult = buttonFilter ? $this.is(buttonFilter) : true;
    return searchResult && buttonResult;
  }
});

$("#filters").on("click", "button", function() {
  buttonFilter = $(this).attr("data-filter");
  $grid.isotope();
});

// use value of search field to filter
var $quicksearch = $("#quicksearch").keyup(
  debounce(function() {
    qsRegex = new RegExp($quicksearch.val(), "gi");
    $grid.isotope();
  })
);

// change is-checked class on buttons
$(".button-group").each(function(i, buttonGroup) {
  var $buttonGroup = $(buttonGroup);
  $buttonGroup.on("click", "button", function() {
    $buttonGroup.find(".is-checked").removeClass("is-checked");
    $(this).addClass("is-checked");
  });
});

// debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
function debounce(fn, threshold) {
  var timeout;
  threshold = threshold || 100;
  return function debounced() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    var args = arguments;
    var _this = this;
    function delayed() {
      fn.apply(_this, args);
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(delayed, threshold);
  };
}
```

HTML (in header, referencing the js):

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML so we can see how you're referencing these files? On your website in the console it's throwing a unexpected token '<' error which usually means you're not referencing your files correctly.

Comment: In your webpage's HTML I can see you referencing jQuery but not the isotope library, which you need in order to use `isotope` in your JavaScript.

Comment: That makes sense! I had never heard of isotope. I tried referencing it multiple different ways with no change. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you referencing it? Can you post some HTML? For more on isotope check out [this link](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I downloaded the js files and am referencing them as

Comment: " <script src="https://www.exploreloudoncounty.com/explore/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
 <script src="https://www.exploreloudoncounty.com/explore/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
" in the head of the html file

Comment: So on your [hosted site](https://www.exploreloudoncounty.com/explore/) I don't see those lines anywhere. If you're using them locally I don't think they will work because `exploreloudoncounty.com` is the domain name not the absolute path relative to the local project. Locally, you should reference the files something like `explore/isotope.pkgd.js`. Do you also by chance have `explore.js` in the `explore` directory? On the hosted site's headers it shows  `<script src="https://www.exploreloudoncounty.com/explore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: Per my previous comment, it is likely there is an issue referencing that file and therefore it is unable to run the JS. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` on the first line of `explore.js` occurs in the console for the hosted site.

Comment: I took explore.js out of the file and put the javascript within the html page. I tried referencing the js files externally (through unpkg, as shown in the link you provided). That is how it is currently, and still not working.

Comment: Is there any way you can include your html in the OP? Just the headers and the script tag that contains your JS when you moved it out of the external file.

Comment: I have edited the OP

Comment: Please include a [mre] in the question itself, not only on an external site. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make it runnable here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Are you able to hit a debugger if you put it after `var $grid = $(".grid").isotope({...})`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. On the isotope website, it says "Package managers: Install with npm: npm install isotope-layout or Install with Bower: bower install isotope-layout --save". I assume I need to do something with that; how?